# AutoIT Close all windows except shutdown

Tags: windows, autoit

I'm building a program that shuts down all open windows after 60 seconds of no mouse movement using AutoIT and a code I found here:
https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/97638-closing-all-open-windows/

I edited it a little such that it looks like this:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 3) ;3 = exact title match
Opt("TrayIconDebug", 1)

$S_running = "check-4-app2" ;name the script
If WinExists($S_running) Then Exit

AutoItWinSetTitle($S_running)

$count = 0
$mousePos = MouseGetPos()
while 1
   $count += 1
   $mousePosNow = mouseGetPos()

   If $mousePosNow[0] <> $mousePos[0] Or $mousePosNow[1] <> $mousePos[1] Then $count = 0

   $mousePos = MouseGetPos()

   ;ToolTip("count = " & $count, 0, 0)

   If $count > 60 Then
      $count = 0
      $var = WinList ()
      $length = UBound($var) - 2
      For $i = 1 to $length
         If BitAnd (WinGetState ($var[$i][1]), 2) And $var[$i][0] <> "" AND $var[$i][0] <> "Program Manager" Then WinClose ($var[$i][1], "")
         Next
   EndIf
   Sleep(1000)
WEnd
```

It does actually close all open windows after 60 seconds but it opens the windows shutdown window as well (like when you press the alt+f4 combination) in windows 7.

How to stop this window from popping up? I just like all windows to close and have a clean desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

First you should do some debug for all values in $var=WinList() to see if some window in your OS is special ,that means, if such window is shutdown, it will trigger windows shutdown, if problem still exists, I found a walkround way , I tried in my computer to do following code

```
WinClose("Close Windows")
; or maybe WinClose("Shutdown Windows")
```

to close what you said "windows shutdown window",maybe you can put this line at the bottom of your code

attention: in my computer, its OS language is not english, so maybe you should first trigger "windows shutdown window" and use AutoIt window info tool to see its window title precisely